# MySql: how to get unique id from two field in a table

Tags: mysql

There is a table called member_info and this table have 2 rows (member_id and sponsor_id)
table looks like :

```
member_id (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
sponsor_id (,1,1,1,2,5,5,5);
```

Now i need to pick those member_id's who are not in sponsor_id like

```
member_id(3,4,6,7,8);
```

Any help Appreciated.

Comment: When you say two rows, is it just two rows with string values or you mean two columns and each row has those ids?

Comment: Can you show your table structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`NOT IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in) function with a sub-query:

```
SELECT `member_id`
FROM `member_info`
WHERE `member_id` NOT IN ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT(`member_id`) FROM `sponsor_info` 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Subqueries introduced with the keyword NOT IN also return a list of zero or more values.

```
SELECT member_id
FROM member_inf
WHERE member_id NOT IN ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT(member_id) FROM sponsor_info
)
```

Comment: You have an erroneous backtick in the table selection. Why not just upvote an answer already posted, rather than re-posting a poorer version?

Comment: @BenM I given u upvote

Comment: thank you. Still better to upvote and avoid duplicate answers, though :)